# Threejs and Reactjs - proper way to clean up the Three code

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I have a json file that I load into the Three.js ObjectLoader and it gets rendered on the screen - it rotates, and I am able to change its colors based on the colors I click - no big deal.

I have a list page that shows a list of product `http://domain.com/products`. I click on the product title, and am routed to `http://domain.com/products/product-name` that shows the THREEjs rendering.

What is problematic is that I am not sure how to handle the clean up of Three. I understand that the `componentWillUnmount()` is responsible for handling the cleanup. What do I put in the `componentWillUnmount()` that will allow me to clean up any webGL context, or free up memory, or clean up any orphaned objects?

Somethings that I've tried:

- If I set all the variables to null in the `componentWillUnmount()`, and I go back to the `http://domain.com/products` page, I get the error that `customize-bow.js:171 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of null` over and over again - which means that the window.requestAnimationFrame() has not been cancelled.
- If I don't have a `componentWillUnmount()`, I do not believe that the memory is cleared

How is it that if the route loads a new component, with new DOM, the webGL is not cleared up? Any ideas to how to handle this issue?

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import BowDetails from './bow-details'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import axios from 'axios'
var OBJLoader = require('three-obj-loader')(THREE)
var OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE)

export default class CustomizeProduct extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
super(props)

this.state = {
  progress: 0,
  colorToSet: '000000',
  rhinoColors: [{color_name: 'Loading...', color_value: '#000000', swatch_url:'initial-pic.png'}],
  canvasWidth: 664,
  canvasHeight: 671,
  viewSize: 100,
  aspectRatio: function () { return (this.canvasWidth / this.canvasHeight) }
}

this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
this.scene = new THREE.Scene()
this.textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-this.state.aspectRatio() * this.state.viewSize / 2, this.state.aspectRatio() * this.state.viewSize / 2, this.state.viewSize / 2, -this.state.viewSize / 2, -40, 80)
this.objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader()

this.basicMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x000000, emissive: 0x000000, specular: 0x000000, shininess: 4, shading: THREE.SmoothShading})
this.camMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x000000, emissive: 0x3c4047, specular: 0x666666, shininess: 1, shading: THREE.SmoothShading})
this.limbMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x000000, emissive: 0x000000, specular: 0x666666, shininess: 1, shading: THREE.SmoothShading})
this.object = null
this.riserTextureMaterial = null
}

componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
   // code to update the props once they come in from Redux ...
  }

componentWillUnmount () {
// What do I put in here to clear out the reference, memory to the webGL
var that = this
window.cancelAnimationFrame(that.renderThree)
this.renderer = null
this.scene = null
this.textureLoader = null
this.camera = null
this.objectLoader = null

this.basicMaterial = null
this.camMaterial = null
this.limbMaterial = null
this.object = null
this.riserTextureMaterial = null

this.mouseBow = null
this.clock = null
this.orbitControls = null
}

render () {
return (
// JSX code to render ...
)
}
}
```